# How to use private members referencing object passed to other function?

Tags: c++

I want to call the public function of a class whose object is passed as a return type from one function to another function.

I was writing the code on an online compiler:

```
//problem is about finding  rectangle matrix with max sum from a given matrix

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class node{

    private:
     int max;
     int up;
     int down;

     public:
     void fill(int a,int b,int c)
     {
        max=a,up=b,down=c;
     }
     int getmax()
     {
        return max;
     }
     int getup()
     {
        return up;
     }
     int getdown()
     {
        return down;
     }
};


node kadane(int tem[1000000],int end1)
{

    node node1;   //created object

    int i,max=-200,csum=0,up,down;

    for(i=0;i<end1;i++)
    {
        if(csum==0)
         up=i;
        csum+=tem[i];
        if(csum>max)
        {
          max=csum;
          down=i;
        }
        if(csum<0)
         csum=0;
    }

    node1.fill(max,up,down);
    cout<<max<<endl;
    return node1; //passing object to main function
}

int main() 
{

    int row,col,m,n,i,j,k;
    cin>>row>>col;
    int a[1000][1000],temp[100000];
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    for(j=0;j<col;j++)
      cin>>a[i][j];

    node node1;  //created object
    int L,R,U,D,msum=-200,csum=0;
    for(i=0;i<col;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<row;j++)
         temp[j]=0;
        for(j=i;j<col;j++)
         {
            for(k=0;k<row;k++)
             temp[k]+=a[k][j];

            node1=kadane(temp,row);
            csum=node1.getmax;//showing the error

            if(csum>msum)
             {
                msum=csum;
                L=i;
                R=j;
                U=node1.getup;  //showing error
                D=node1.getdown; //showing error
             }
         }
    }

    cout<<"UDLR"<<U<<D<<L<<R;

    for(i=U;i<=D;i++)
     {
        cout<<endl;
        for(j=L;j<=R;j++)
          cout<<a[i][j]<<"\t";
     }

    cout<<endl<<"sum"<<msum;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output:

sum as 18

But instead I am getting error as:

```
prog.cpp:74:16: error: cannot convert ‘node::getmax’ from type ‘int (node::)()’ to type ‘int’
     csum=node1.getmax;
                ^~~~~~
prog.cpp:81:15: error: cannot convert ‘node::getup’ from type ‘int (node::)()’ to type ‘int’
       U=node1.getup;
               ^~~~~
prog.cpp:82:15: error: cannot convert ‘node::getdown’ from type ‘int (node::)()’ to type ‘int’
       D=node1.getdown;
               ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: ```node1.getmax()``` instead of ```node1.getmax```?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not calling the methods try csum=node1.getmax().

The compile error is telling you that the raw method is not an integer, it's a method pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`getmax()` is a function. It needs parenthesis.

Try this instead:

```
csum=node1.getmax();
```

You're gonna need to do the exact same thing on these lines too:

```
U=node1.getup();     
D=node1.getdown();
```

**Edit:** I should also mention that your problem has nothing to do with accessing private members. Rather, it has to do with the fact that `getmax()`,`getup()`, and `getdown()` are functions. In C++, calling functions require parenthesis after the name.